# What's the most effective way to create a convincing horizon in the game engine?

Tags: rendering, materials, game-engine, light

I would like to have an outdoor area in my game, however, my sky and horizon look like they're definitely a skybox, which they are. this is not due to bad unwrapping.

I just want to know if there is a convincing way to create a sky by changing the colors of Blenders natural 'sky' default gray.

I don't need to have clouds or any of that jargon, just want the light and colors, like in this picture by gandalf3

[image]

That's the effect I need.

Comment: I used the mist pass to do that, perhaps using the mist in the game engine will work for you.

Comment: Did you use a skybox?

Comment: No. I used cycles with a HDR environment map

Comment: May you please go into a little more detail, I've never used environment maps.

Comment: It won't work for the GE.. A skybox is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling *Mist* in world settings:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**[Example .blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32141)**